# White space from appsettings in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, .net-core

So as I was trying to read some configuration from a Json config file

```
(ProjectSettings.json)
"config" : "this {0} , and {1}"
```

when I read this in my project I do a

```
string.convert(config, string1, string2)
```

and it throw me an exception

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

So after debugging, I have find that after reading it from the file it add a white space between the curly bracket and the number,

```
"this { 0} , and { 1}"
```

so I have come up with a quick fix:

```
Config.Replace("{ ","{");
```

and it works just fine.

So, my question is the following:

**Is this normal, and am still not sure what I have done wrong to have those white spaces, and how can I remove them properly?**

Comment: what do u use to read settings from file? stream?

Comment: this is what i use :` public IConfiguration Config{ get; set; }`

Comment: can u give all your coding, your startup, config file, etc..

Comment: @darcane , i have find the issue,,,, i cleaned my code, and it worked, even tho i went to **bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1 ** to make sure its fine,,, but still have no idea what just happen.
so,,, cleaning my code fixed it :/

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted all config files, and cleaned my code, re-created them, and it worked fine.